# How to run this Go application locally?

Tags: javascript, git, go, multiplayer

I want to be able to run the application from the repository https://github.com/jbowens/codenames locally on my machine. Is it possible?

Steps I've tried:

- Installed Go. Added PATH variable.
- Cloned the repository to my machine in the right go path location.
- Opened command prompt and ran the command "go run main.go" from the "cmd" folder

I really don't know anything about Go so maybe I just have to run another command or install dependencies or whatever. If someone could figure this out I would be super happy! This is an awesome game I would like to play from my machine.

Comment: Have you tried to access by `localhost:9091` as shown [here](https://github.com/jbowens/codenames/blob/master/cmd/codenames/main.go#L14)?

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried but I feel like there might be something wrong with the code because if you run main.go right after running it says it can't find one of the txt files with the words (game-id-words.txt).

Comment: What repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are just typing `go build` from the `cmd/codenames` directory, creating a binary called 'codenames' in that directory and running from there.

Unfortunately the app is hard-coded to look for its assets in a ./assets/ directory relative to the binary.

So you want your binary in the root of the app:

i.e

- from the `cmd/codenames` directory `go build -o ../../run-me-from-here`
- then from the root of the app `./run-me-from-here`

  .

Comment: THANK YOU! I just moved the codenames.exe that I got from the go build to the root and when I ran it, it worked!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Running them locally is very easy in go

I usually run go get while in my local go directory.

Go get https://github.com/jbowens/codenames

Comment: Yeah that's what you do to get the project files locally. I'm having trouble getting the app up and running since there seems to be a problem with how the code is written. If you can figure out how to run the code on your machine then please let me know what you did :)

Answer (score -4):

Set gopath and goroot then install dependencies.